# How to split a file by a multi-character delimiter?

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, sed

On Unix, without adding anything to the OS (i.e. only using *grep*, *awk*, *sed*, *cut*, etc.), how can I extract the "text" line in only the "codeView" section (and ignore that in the "probableStartLocationView" section)?

```
. . .
      "events" : [ {
"id" : "12345",
"important" : true,
"type" : "Creation",
"description" : "Something happened here",
"extraDetails" : null,
"codeView" : {
  "lines" : [ {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "NORMAL_CODE",
      "value" : "str = wrapper.getParameter("
    }, {
      "type" : "CODE_STRING",
      "value" : "&quot;abcd&quot;"
    }, {
      "type" : "NORMAL_CODE",
      "value" : ")"
    } ],
    "text" : "str = wrapper.getParameter(&quot;abcd&quot;)"
  } ],
  "nested" : false
},
"probableStartLocationView" : {
  "lines" : [ {
    "fragments" : [ {
      "type" : "STACKTRACE_LINE",
      "value" : "&lt;init&gt;() @ JSONInputData.java:72"
    } ],
    "text" : "&lt;init&gt;() @ JSONInputData.java:72"
  } ],
  "nested" : false
},
. . .
```

Comment: Hm. Parsing `json` with `grep, awk, sed, cut, etc.` isn't the best idea...  You can check an [json parser written in awk](https://github.com/step-/JSON.awk) or the [JSON.sh](https://github.com/dominictarr/JSON.sh) but using `jq` is really the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really need to use OS included tools only, you can try something like that:

```
JSONString='"codeView" : { "lines" : [ { "fragments" : [ { "type" : "NORMAL_CODE", "value" : "str = wrapper.getParameter(" }, { "type" : "CODE_STRING", "value" : "&quot;abcd&quot;" }, { "type" : "NORMAL_CODE", "value" : ")" } ], "text" : "str = wrapper.getParameter(&quot;abcd&quot;)" } ], "nested" : false },'

function jsonParse() {
    awk -F"[,:}]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/'$1'\042/){print $(i+1)}}}' | tr -d '"' | sed -n 1p
}

printf "$(echo $JSONString | jsonParse text)"
```

**Please note:** This is not at all a safe way to do it, as it doesn't *parse* the JSON. It just extracts the `text` key.

Demo available [here](http://tpcg.io/ftZOO0).

However since in your example there are two `text` keys, this code will only get the **first** one. If you need any `text` key after the first one, you have to alter the code above a bit. You need to make `sed` target the exact line you need. Say you need the second `text` in the `"codeView"` block, you would write

```
sed -n 2p
```

instead of `sed -n 1p`.

Demo for the second `text` key is [here](http://tpcg.io/PAiAZG).

Answer (score 0):

The right way with ***jq*** processor (assuming that `.events` is a key on the 1st level of the input JSON structure):

```
jq -r '.events[0].codeView.lines[0].text' input.json
```

The output:

```
str = wrapper.getParameter(&quot;abcd&quot;)
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^"[^"]*"/h;//!G;/"text".*\n"codeView"/P;d' file
```

Save the current section in the hold space and append it to each line within that section. Using the grep-like option `-n` prevents lines being printed as normal and using a regexp and the `P` command print the line that meets your criteria.